# How can I limit the rendering done by QScrollArea?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a Widget that is huge (80,000 px long maybe? 800 elements at 100px each) because it lays out many smaller widgets. I've put the huge widget into a QScrollArea. But the scroll area still renders the entire widget. This causes manipulation of the widget to be choppy, and I want things to be smoother.

Instead I want the QScrollAea to be intelligent enough to only render the elements that I know will be displayed. (The elements are ordered and are all the same fixed size, so this computation should be fast)

What's the best approach to go about this? Should QScrollArea already be doing this?

Does QListView already implement this functionality? (But I want my own custom widget in there it has buttons that interact with the user, QListWiget doesn't cut it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a QGraphicsView?  This allows scrolling in addition to efficient rendering of only the visible objects (and plenty of other benefits such as hit testing).

Comment: So these are QWidgets that I'm displaying with buttons and CSS. I'd like to reuse this code that I have. But this does look very promising.

Comment: You can try setting the clipping rect and your minimal size.  Maybe the sizer hints aren't being updated properly and the entire view is being re-rendered (I think QScrollArea also does some intelligent rendering by default, but it's sizer dependent).  I'd suggest seeing if your buttons just are slow as well.  The CSS rendering might be your bottleneck.

Comment: So what exactly are the "sizer" hints? Do you mean just min/max Size? So currently everything only gets re-rendered when I drag horizontally. Are these suggestions for using QGraphicsView or QScrollArea?

Comment: Fixing up the size hints in my code drastically improved performance. There was also a strange behavior/bug with having text wrapping with my QLabel that was hiding the fact that I incorrect size settings.